# Can't find window in c++

Tags: c++

I'm pretty new to C++ and I'm making a hack for Assassin's Creed Odyssey, however I can't get my code to find the window.

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL,  "Assassin's Creed® Odyssey");
```

Window name(s):

[image]

EDIT: Got it to work, the apostrophe is different than a normal one, for whoever needs it, this is the correct window name `Assassin’s Creed® Odyssey`

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't openly be saying that you're hacking a commercial product. Just a thought, you do what you want.

Comment: Realize that the authors of some of the software you feel you need to hack may be members here.

Comment: All the same, I believe Stack Overflow itself doesn't discriminate when it comes to the intentions behind a question.

Comment: @DeiDei Ubisoft is fine if the game is single player, it's just multiplayer games that get you into trouble.

Comment: @TateGreeves you should have posted your solution as an answer instead of as an edit to your question. You can post answers to your own questions.  Now, in its current form, your question is has basically become irrelevant for a Q+A site and should be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Ahh. FindWindowA expects an ANSI string. To use the ® in Microsoft Windows, you should use the wstring variant, and use a wstring literal:

`HWND hwnd = FindWindowW(NULL,  L"Assassin's Creed® Odyssey");`

Do check that you are using the correct type of apostrophe. I can't tell from the screen capture whether it is an ANSI apostrophe or a right single quote.

The L before the " indicates that it is a wstring. In Windows computers this is pretty much UTF-16, though Microsoft Windows doesn't quite meet all the UTF-16 standards.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal for more information on the various type of string literals.

This microsoft article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/working-with-strings, explains the difference between the ANSI functions (ending with 'A') and the Unicode functions (ending with 'W').

Comment: Thanks alot, though that may have been the case, I went into the Spy++ and copied and pasted the window caption, the apostrophe was different than what I put in the HWND. It works now.